# How to split readLines output into text array R

Tags: r, csv, text, readlines

I am using readLines to read the first 4 lines of csv files to determine what the headers are so I can concatenate files with similar headers.  readLines produces difficult output that looks like this (this is only the first line as an example):

```
output <- readLines(one_min_file, n = 4)

[1] "\"TOA5\",\"Shelton 2SW\",\"CR1000\",\"62704\",\"CR1000.Std.27\",\"CPU:0044-20201101.CR1\",\"35516\",\"OneMinute\""
```

How do I parse this into a text array or something that looks like this, or the same array that this produces?

```
c('TOA5','Shelton 2SW','CR1000','62704','CR1000.Std.27','CPU:0044-20201101.CR1','35516','OneMinute')


EDIT:
dput(readLines(one_min_files[h1], n = 1))
"\"TOA5\",\"Shelton 2SW\",\"CR1000\",\"62704\",\"CR1000.Std.27\",\"CPU:0044-20201101.CR1\",\"35516\",\"OneMinute\""
```

Comment: Could you include  the result of  `dput(output)` ?

Comment: It would be bit better without any manual alterations and for all 4 lines, i.e. the whole thing as `c(...)`.  Though that what you see is probably just the way quoted strings are printed. Try `cat(paste(output, collapse = "\n"))` or `stringr::str_view(output)` to print with unescaped quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing double quotes and splitting by `,`:

```r
(output <- c("\"TOA5\",\"Shelton 2SW\",\"CR1000\",\"62704\",\"CR1000.Std.27\",\"CPU:0044-20201101.CR1\",\"35516\",\"OneMinute\""))
#> [1] "\"TOA5\",\"Shelton 2SW\",\"CR1000\",\"62704\",\"CR1000.Std.27\",\"CPU:0044-20201101.CR1\",\"35516\",\"OneMinute\""

gsub('"', '', output, fixed = TRUE) |> strsplit(",") |> unlist()
#> [1] "TOA5"                  "Shelton 2SW"           "CR1000"               
#> [4] "62704"                 "CR1000.Std.27"         "CPU:0044-20201101.CR1"
#> [7] "35516"                 "OneMinute"
```

Or parse the line with `read.csv()`:

```r
read.csv(text = output, header = FALSE)[1,] |> unlist() |> unname()
#> [1] "TOA5"                  "Shelton 2SW"           "CR1000"               
#> [4] "62704"                 "CR1000.Std.27"         "CPU:0044-20201101.CR1"
#> [7] "35516"                 "OneMinute"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>